# If $H$ is a proper subgroup of a finite $p$-group, then $H$ is maximal or it's contained in $\text{Frat}(G)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

As the title says, I have this assertion about the structure of maximal subgroups of a finite $p$-group $G$: if $H<G$ then $H$ is maximal or $H\leq \text{Frat}(G)$, which is used to prove that if $p$ is an odd prime and $G$ is a finite $p$-group with a unique minimal subgroup, then $G$ is cyclic.

But it seems to me not to be true in general (e.g. in the additive group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^3$, being elementary abelian, the maximal subgroups are exactly the "planes" over the field with $p$ elements, so the Frattini subgroup is trivial and if we take one dimensional sub-vector spaces we see that the assertion is false). Now my question is: under what hypotheses is that result true, in order to use it to prove the second result?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since every proper subgroup is contained in a maximal subgroup, the result is false as soon as the group has two maximal subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$, with another subgroup $K$ such that $K<H_1$ and $K\not<H_2$.

Comment: For finite $p$-groups it is only true in cyclic groups, $C_p \times C_p$, and $Q_8$.

Comment: Ok, so we agree that the first result is false in general. But then how can I prove the second fact without using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, the claim is not true.

But the claim you wanted to use it for is, and it is in fact fairly straight forward:

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group with $p$ odd having a unique minimal (non-trivial) subgroup $H$. We can clearly assume that $|G|\geq p^3$ and that $G$ is not abelian, and we see that $|H| = p$ and $H$ is central.

Now consider $G/H$, which is not cyclic by assumption, so by induction, it has at least two subgroups of order $p$, $K_1$ and $K_2$. We may assume that $K_1$ is central, so $K_1K_2$ is a subgroup of order $p^2$ which is not cyclic. Now this gives us a non-cyclic subgroup of $G$ of order $p^3$, so we are left with checking that non-cyclic groups of order $p^3$ have more than one subgroup of order $p$, which is easy.

An alternative, which is less elementary but shorter is to invoke the more general result that if $G$ is a finite non-cyclic $p$-group which has a unique subgroup of order $1 < p^k < |G|$ for some $k$ then $k = 1$, $p=2$ and $G$ is generalized quaternion (this can be found for example in Berkovich's book).

Comment: Ok, now it's clear, thanks a lot Tobias!